# Launch Minecraft 1.7.10 from command line

Tags: java, minecraft

I've been trying to make a batch file in Windows to directly launch Minecraft 1.7.10. However, the method I tried had changed since the new launcher has been released. Does anyone know how I could directly launch it from the command line, with my username and session token? I legally own Minecraft, so I should be able to use my session token and username.

Comment: How are you going to get a session token?

Comment: The session token is in my launcer_profiles.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Minecraft 1.7.10 normally then use task manager or another program to get the command used to launch the program.